# How to add dynamic TimeoutSeconds for activity in AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-step-functions

I have an activity in step function with `TimeoutSeconds`, like this:

```
ActivityWaiting:
    Type: Task
    ResultPath: $.output
    Resource: arn:aws:states:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:activity:myActivity
    TimeoutSeconds: 3600
```

I would like to control the value of `TimeoutSeconds` and to change it with a parameter from the previous step.
I've tried something like that:

```
ActivityWaiting:
    Type: Task
    ResultPath: $.output
    Resource: arn:aws:states:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:activity:myActivity
    TimeoutSeconds: $.myTimeout
```

But unfortunately, it didn't work.

**Edit**:
I would like to calculate/define the time `myTimeout` before executing the step function with python. Something like that:

```
data['myTimeout'] = getTimeout() #dymanic time in the seconds(ex 15000)

response = step_functions.start_execution(stateMachineArn=state_machine, input=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Can you please show us where "$.expirydate" is calculated/defined? TimeoutSeconds needs to be defined in seconds but your passed parameter is "expirydate"???

Comment: @JorgRoper Thank you, I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I want this feature so bad, alas it does not seem to be supported at the moment. If anything, you'd have to have the trailing `$` like this `TimeoutSeconds.$: $.myTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a solution for dynamic timeout.

I've made a workaround using [AWS Choice state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html)

I was needed to wait for an answer from a microservice, the time depended on the quantity of objects, which I've sent to it.
Process of each object took like 3 minutes in average, therefore the timeout could be from 3 minutes and more.

All the results, my microservice has written into a DB.
So I created a lambda, that checks the DB in a loop.

The exit condition is

- Getting all the results in DB
- Waiting time has ended, which calculated dynamically for each every execution

I work with [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) framework, here is my final solution:

```
VerifyLambda:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:verify-step
    Next: IsFinished
IsFinished:
    Type: Choice
    Choices:
        - Variable: $.isFinish
        BooleanEquals: false
        Next: Wait 3m
    Default: NextLambdaStep
Wait 3m:
    Type: Wait
    Seconds: 180
    Next: VerifyLambda
NextLambdaStep: ...
```

[image: Step function Visualization]

Answer (score 6):

This feature is available now. There is a `TimeoutSecondsPath` parameter that can be used instead of `TimeoutSeconds`. `TimeoutSecondsPath` accepts a reference path (e.g. `"$.myTimeout"`)